# How to define ImageField in abstract model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have class for upload_to:

```
class PathAndRename(object):
    def __init__(self, sub_path):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)

        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)
```

I have created abstract class for preview:

```
class PreviewAbstract(models.Model):
    upload_path = ''

    preview = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='Превью',
        upload_to=PathAndRename(upload_path)
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I want to be able to inherite this model like:

```
class ChildClass(PreviewAbstract):
    upload_path = 'folder_name'
```

, but in saves images in "root" folder

How can i do it?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem this way:

```
@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):

    def __init__(self, sub_path=None):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        if instance.pk:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.pk, ext)
        else:
            filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)

        if self.path is not None:
            return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

        return os.path.join(instance.upload_path, filename)
```